# What is a good way to create movement bounds for a "room" in an HTML5 Canvas game?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I've been having a go and building a little game using canvas and Javascript, and I've got to the point of having a little character move around the screen, with a flat image drawn in the background depicting a room of sorts.

What would be the best way to approach defining where the player entity can and cannot move? If it's just a square room, that's easy enough to check the edges vs. the player x and y, but it gets more complicated if I have varying shapes of background that I might want the player to be able to move to.

Is there a way to detect intersection of drawn images on canvas? If so, I could perhaps render the "walls" as separate to the main background, and check if the player has hit any of those. Or I might be over-thinking what has a simpler solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code for us to work with ^_^

Comment: ...alternatively, don't add any code :D

Answer (score 3):

Please give more next time. Is this a 2D top-down game? I'll assume so.

There are several ways, depending on what you want to do and the level of granularity.

If the rooms are almost all rectangular, you could just see if the object is fully contained within them.

If not, you could use rect-intersects-line algorithms, or else you could turn the map into one big path (with the center of the path being either hollow or not) and use `IsPointInPath` (I'd suggest making your own though and not using Canvas' one) to see if a few key points of player geometry are all inside (or outside)

Finally, if you want **per-pixel** collision, you should make a simplified black png map (or something similar) of your level and use a ghost canvas, like I do for hit testing [here.](http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes) Then test several pixels on the player's silhouette and see if they are black or not. If any of them are not black, the player is out of bounds!

Answer (score 1):

I for once tried to create a simple game on html5 canvas similar to what you are currently working on (I guess it's a common idea).
What I suggest is that you work on a collision engine, at least this was my idea :

- create another layer on top of the one you have as a background,
- assign the same boundary image (transparent) to each object you want your player not to go through,
- then you have to calculate when the player XY coordinates are over that object
- if(collides){ do not go through } else { go }

This way you can stop player moving through a wall or otherwise solid object.

I looked up HTML5+Collision on Google but nothing interesting showed up, maybe you should try different searches, or be the first to implement the idea (mine is just at a basic stage).

Answer (score 0):

### EDITED:

You would probably have to define some SVG shapes or have a "map array" of some kind..

i.e.

```
 map = {
      [0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0]
    }
```

Comment: Hi - yep, this is fine if it's just a square room as I mentioned, but if it's a room with x walls, multiple paths, or even curved edges, then this approach doesn't really work as width isn't a constant, and the entire width from left to right isn't necessarily passable.

Comment: Please could you edit your question to add in these details including: the code you have thus far and possibly an image of the map? (am I asking too much?) :)